# Restful API c# Entityframework

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to get a foodcontroller to display data from a database and i get an error saying:

'ArrayOfstring:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

Do i need to install something to get this to display on the webpage?

```
public class FoodsController : ApiController
{
    public object Get()
    {
        FoodDiaryContext cs = new FoodDiaryContext();
        return cs.Foods.OrderByDescending(c => c.Description);
    }
}
```

My food entity is really basic just has two property's - id and description.

Thanks for the help.

Heres the  FoodDiaryContext

```
public class FoodDiaryContext:DbContext
    {
        public FoodDiaryContext()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide more detail about the `FoodDiaryContext` class.

Comment: Return `Food` instead of object. Try returning List<Foods>

Comment: Have you got any relations in your class Food to other classes?

Comment: No i tried to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: i got it work when i do this public List<Food> Get()
        {
            FoodDiaryContext cs = new FoodDiaryContext();
            var foodquery = cs.Foods.OrderByDescending(c => c.Description);
    return foodquery.ToList()}

Comment: congrats for solving the problem I think you maybe would not need foodquery.ToList() if you would use ICollection<Food> for return type

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought that if the return type is an object that it would return everything but i must be wrong :(

Comment: I think your problem is that you were trying to return an unenumerated query. Calling ToList() enumerates it, which allows the serialiser to work.